# Can SQL interleave data based on a range limit?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following data

**Table 1**

```
Key  Value
---  -----
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
E    5
F    6
G    7
H    8
I    9
J    10
```

**Table 2**

```
Q  MaxValue
-  --------
X  3
Y  6
Z  10
```

I'm trying to create a join that matches table 1 with table 2 when the values of table 1 are less than or equal to MaxValue in table 2, but only where they are greater than the prior MaxValue, like so

**Result**

```
Key  Value  Q  MaxValue
---  -----  -  --------
A    1      X  3
B    2      X  3
C    3      X  3
D    4      Y  6
E    5      Y  6
F    6      Y  6
G    7      Z  10
H    8      Z  10
I    9      Z  10
J    10     Z  10
```

Here you see that while A-F all meet the criteria of being less than or equal to 6 (Y's MaxValue), I want A-C to be matched only to X since they already match X's criteria of being less than 3, X being the 'prior max value'.

So can this be achieved in SQL?

Comment: You might need to use dynamic SQL to handle this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no, it does not. It is easier in dynamic SQL, but suitable nested select will do.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very pretty but it should work for you:

```
select Z.[Key], Z.Value, T2.Q, Z.MaxValue from
(
    select Y.[Key], Y.Value, Min(MaxValue) as MaxValue from 
    (
        select T1.*, T2.MaxValue from Table1 T1 cross join Table2 T2
    ) Y 
    where Y.Value <= Y.MaxValue 
    group by Y.[Key], Y.Value       
) Z 
inner join Table2 T2 on Z.MaxValue = T2.MaxValue
```

- `select T1.Value, T2.MaxValue from Table1 T1 cross join Table2 T2` gets all possible combinations of Value and MaxValue.
- Then I'm grouping it based on `Value` and `Key` and including the condition `where Y.Value <= Y.MaxValue` to exclude combinations where there are overlapping `MaxValue`s for the same `Value`.
- Finally, I'm getting the original `Q` column from `Table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully help

```
select  [Key],
        [Value],
        (SELECT [Q] FROM [TB2] T2 WHERE [MaxValue] IN (SELECT MIN(MaxValue) FROM [Table1] T2 WHERE T1.[Value]<= T2.[MaxValue])) AS Q,
        (SELECT MIN(MaxValue) FROM [TB2] T2 WHERE T1.[Value]<= T2.[MaxValue]) AS MaxValue
FROM [Table2] T1
```